# How can i set "yesterday" in a variable? - Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm working on Azure Data Factory, and i'm looking to set one variable in my pipeline, that always represent the past day (yesterday). This is the solution that i found for the poor syntax integration via API with a CosmosDB that MS ADF has, so i cannot use CAST GETDATE -1 as i already used in other pipelines for SQL relational databases.

[image: Pipeline]

Already tried with all the possible solutions that i found on Microsoft Documentation:

Set the variable by the Activity "Set Variable", in order to pass through a parameter in my pipeline.
Set the parameter with the formula directly

Formula: `@addDays(utcnow(), -1)`

I am having difficulties calling the variable / parameter in my "Copy Data" Activity, all the logic for the pipelines runs OK with parameters FromDate / ToDate. But when i replace it with a single parameter / variable :
`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Created = @variables('FechaAyer')`

Gives me the following error:

`"the function call must take the completion string"`

I think i'm missing something

Comment: Your code is correct for getting the current timestamp minus 1 day. Can you elaborate on the problem? Are you receiving an error? What is the result of your execution? What is not working? Are you just looking for a different format?

Comment: Sure, i'm working on a incremental pipeline, which aims to run every night, upserting registers from yesterday.
i'm having difficulties calling the variable / parameter in my "Copy Data" Activity, all the logic for the pipelines runs OK with parameters FromDate / ToDate. But when i  reeplace it with a single parameter / variable :

SELECT * FROM c 
WHERE c.Created = @variables('FechaAyer')

Gives me the following error:

"the function call must take the completion string"

I think i'm missing something :/

Comment: Try putting your SQL statement into an expression using concat to build it out. Not as pretty but more reliable than direct interpolation.

Comment: @MarianoVillaverde - please *edit your question* to provide more details instead of posting as a comment, especially when providing code/queries/data/errors - that way, you can properly format it for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your query in lookup and I got same error.

[image]

While using the ADF variables in queries, you need to use String interpolation or build the query using concat as suggested in comments.

In your pipeline you are using an array variable and comparing it with the values of cosmos.
To achieve your requirement, use the string type variable.

Go through the below sample demo:

Here, I have taken a string type variable and given below dynamic content to get the yesterday date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. You can give your date format.

```
@addDays(utcnow(), -1,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

[image]

Now, I have used string interpolation in the query. For sample I have taken lookup.

```
select * from c where c.mydate='@{variables('forAyear')}'
```

[image]

**Result**:

[image]